# Get width of not displayed images with JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

Please have a look at the **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73rr8/1/)**

When I run it, I want to get the width of the images but I get following values (have a look in the JS console)

```
400 
0 
575 
533 
0
...
```

Some are zero. I don't know why this happens. And it's always different. If you refresh the fiddle (F5) some times you will get different values for the width. Sometimes the correct width, sometimes just 0.

Local (with images saved to my hard disc) it's the same.

Does anyone have a suggestion whats wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting `0` periodically because you're not waiting for the images to be loaded before you measure them. When you measure an image that hasn't been loaded yet, you get back `0`.

If you change your code showing the widths to check to see if the image has been loaded yet, and wait for load if not, you see non-zero widths:

```
if (this.complete) {
    console.log($(this).width() + " (didn't have to wait)");
} else {
    $(this).one("load", function() {
        console.log($(this).width() + " (had to wait)");
    });
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73rr8/3/)

Here's a sample of the output I get with a cleared browser cache, when I go to [the embedded version of that fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73rr8/3/embedded/result/):

```
400 (didn't have to wait)
575 (didn't have to wait)
533 (didn't have to wait)
452 (had to wait)
534 (had to wait)
375 (had to wait)
```

Here's a slightly more paranoid version of that code, which is probably the approach I'd take:

```
var img = $(this);
img.one("load.showcase", function() {
    console.log(img.width() + " (had to wait)");
});
if (this.complete) {
    img.off("load.showcase");
    console.log(img.width() + " (didn't have to wait)");
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73rr8/4/)

Why hook the event only to remove it immediately after? Because although JavaScript has only one main UI thread in web browsers, web browsers *themselves* are multi-threaded. If we check `this.complete` *first*, this would be a perfectly valid sequence:

1. We check it and see `false`
2. The browser finishes loading the image, looks to see if there are any load handlers for it to queue, sees there aren't, and so doesn't queue any handler calls
3. Our next line runs to hook the event

...meaning we don't get any notification for the image. It's the same reason one must *always* hook `load` before setting `src`, if adding images dynamically.

Comment: Thank you very, very much. I already assumed something like that, but I wasn't sure. Great example and thanks for the detailed explanation of your approach.